# recon_alloc:memory(allocated) is much smaller than the memory allocated from os

Tags: erlang, system

```
> recon_alloc:memory(allocated).
49221632
> os:getpid().
"5656"
```

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                 
22443 root      20   0 5763100 1.345g   2964 S   1.1  8.7  96:59.10 beam.smp                                                
 5656 root      20   0 5253972 1.001g   4736 S   2.2  6.4  35:05.21 beam.smp
```

I find the memory I see in erlang vm is much smaller than the memory allocated from os, which means my erlang node has a memory leak.
Is there a way to locate where a memory leak has occurred?

Answer (score 1):

I've written https://www.erlang-in-anger.com/ to go with `recon` to explain some of these things. It's all free, and contains mostly everything you'll need for this issue. You will want to look at Chapter 7 (Memory leaks), and particularly section 7.3 on Memory fragmentation.

Essentially, you can look at other functions in recon_memory to find about which type of allocator is seeing lower usage in its allocation for various block sizes, and then play with the allocation strategies to optimize.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I am your fans.But I don't think the problem is memory fragmentation.I have already seen the usage of sbcs and mbcs.They are at a healthy point.Is it possible that the nif caused these memory leaks?

Comment: it's possible; NIFs will usually be in no specific allocators, and then another tool (specifically geared towards C code analysis) might make more sense